# First time new user login requires password change in HANA DB

Tags: hana-studio

As I login from a new user created through HANA Studio, it asks for Password change.

I'm new to the environment and don't know how to disable this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a system behavior that can be configured either via parameter configuration

( indexserver.ini -> [password policy] -> force_first_password_change )

or

via the Security editor in SAP HANA studio -> "Password Policy" -> [ ] User must change password at first logon.

It's also explained in the Administration Guide documentation (built into the SAP HANA studio help).